# Issue with Gnuwin32 make

Tags: makefile, gnuwin32

Trying to compile the makefiles from midifile.sapp.org gives me the following output:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which wget, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, which curl, ...) failed.
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, uname, ...) failed.
make[1]: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: [makedirs] Error 1 (ignored)
'LANG' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
make[1]: *** [Binasc.o] Error 1
make: *** [library] Error 2
```

No idea what any of this means, or why it isn't working. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the commands that make tried to invoke, not just the errors that resulted from those commands.  However, note that the first three errors are trying to invoke commands (`which` and `uname`) that are UNIX commands, not Windows commands: unless you're running in a cygwin environment those commands won't work.  Maybe your makefile is written for UNIX systems like GNU/Linux, not Windows?

Comment: I tried on cygwin and got the same errors